# Django - Simplify Proxy Model to single class

Tags: django, django-models

I have User table in my DB, they can be active or inactive. If I only want to query on active user, I define a Proxy Model like following.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active      = models.BooleanField()


class UserActive(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(UserActive, self).get_queryset().filter(active=True)

class ActiveUser(User):
    objects = UserActive()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Then by working with ActiveUser, I can do my calculation/statistic with only active user.

The problem is, I need to define both UserActive and ActiveUser class, it seems awkward to me. Because with each main class (in this case is User), we need to define two other classes. Imaging we have several other model need to implement Proxy, the code would look messy. May I know if we can have more elegant way ?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: No, you can define a proxy that you do not use, and personally I would really avoid ovewriting the `.objects` manager, and thus use `User.active_objects` as manager, since now you suggest syntactically that there is such a thing as an `ActiveUser` object.

Comment: @Willem: Can you share why avoid overwriting the .objects manager ? in my case I use ActiveUser.objects.get(....) or ActiveUser.objects.filter(.....) all the time

Comment: Because this basically invalidates one of the principles of Python: "Explcit is better than implicit". Imagine that you pass `ActiveUser` as a parameter, and then `klass.objects` is called. The function expects to retrieve *all* objects. But it does not. My experience with such practices is that eventually these result in a lot of extra errors.

Comment: A proxy model is typically used to patch *behavior* of *instances* of that proxy model, but what you here construct are *thin proxies*. They do not really add extra functionality: these only are used to "*patch*" the object manager.

Answer (score 2):

I would really avoid overwriting the `.objects` manager, and use this as some sort of implicit filtering. The *Zen of Python* is *explicit is better than implicit*, by using `ActiveUser`, you basically implement a filtering manager, but propose it like the entire set.

Perhaps a more elegant solution is to define *multiple* managers. So we can construct a *filtering manager* decorator:

```
def filter_manager(**kwargs):
    def decorator(klass):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super(klass, self).get_queryset().filter(**kwargs)
        klass.get_queryset = get_queryset
        return klass
    return decorator
```

This decorator will however throw away a `get_queryset` that is defined on the manager itself, so you can not perform an extra patch with this.

Now we can define some managers in a rather elegant way:

```
@filter_manager(active=True)
class ActiveManager(models.Manager):
    pass

@filter_manager(active=False)
class InactiveManager(models.Manager):
    pass
```

Finally we can add these managers to the `User` model, and use *explicit names*:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active      = models.BooleanField()

    objects = models.Manager()
    active_users = ActiveManager()
    inactive_users = InactiveManager()
```

So now we can use `User.active_users` to query for the active users. We thus have no proxy models, and can query with `User.active_users.count()` for example (well we can perform all operations like with `.objects` but then for `.active_users`.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I found an issue with this approach. All of my previous query like User.objects.all() / User.objects.filter(......) become invalid with this error:type object 'User' has no attribute 'objects'. Now I have to go one by one to edit objects to active_users ?

Comment: No, `User` should still have `object`s. Did you set it to `None` by any chance?

Comment: After all we did *not* remove the `.objects` manager, we only have added two more.

Comment: That's weird. I am verifying

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Django project, with only User model. My models.py look like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

def filter_manager(**kwargs):
    def decorator(klass):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super(klass, self).get_queryset().filter(**kwargs)
        klass.get_queryset = get_queryset
        return klass
    return decorator


@filter_manager(active=True)
class ActiveManager(models.Manager):
    pass

@filter_manager(active=False)
class InactiveManager(models.Manager):
    pass

class User(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active      = models.BooleanField()
    active_user = ActiveManager()
```

When I tried User.objects.all().

Error: `type object 'User' has no attribute 'objects'`

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: My view
`def test(request):
    user = User.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse('ALL USER')`


Error:

`AttributeError at /test/
type object 'User' has no attribute 'objects'`

Comment: What does it print if you write `print(User.__qualname__)` before the `User.objects.all()`?

Comment: `print(User.__qualname__)
AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute '__qualname__'`

Comment: then `User` is not a class here, you probably have overwritten the reference (with a certain object), a class has a `__qualname__`.

Comment: active_user = ActiveManager() --> This line overwrite the reference

Comment: But the `active_user` is an attribute of the class, and it has not the slightest impact on `__qualname__`. What if you only remove the two managers. Does it work then?

Comment: What do you mean by remove the two managers. ? I recommend you just simply create a new django project on your side , copy my posted **models.py** , then in the view just simply call User.objects.all() to see if it works. If it works in your side , there must be something wrong in my side

Comment: well aI already did that :). The point is that I can not reproduce it. And based on the fact that your `User` has no `__qualname__` I thus have the idea that somewhere you have overwritten `User` with something else. What if you `print(User)`?

Comment: `<class 'uht.models.User'>`. Here uht is my app name

Comment: Or may be we used different Django version? I'm running 1.11, Python 2.7

Comment: what if you add an extra `objects = models.Manager()`?